# Finding $\int_{0}^a\int_{0}^\sqrt{a^2-y^2} (2x-3xy)\,dx\,dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

$$\int_{0}^a\int_{0}^\sqrt{a^2-y^2} (2x-3xy)\,dx\,dy$$

> In this question I want to solve it by using polar coordinates while taking $x=r\cos{\theta}$ and  $y=r\sin{\theta}$, I know that putting values of $x$ and $y$ in function and replacing $dx\,dy$ by $r\,dr\,d\theta$, but how will I determine the limits of Transformed Integral? Is there any other way without looking at the geometry of curves?

Comment: The most common way to work this out is to do a sketch of the integration region. You should realise the region is a quarter circle in the first quadrant with radius $a$ and centre $(0,0)$. So the bounds should become $0\le r\le a$ and $0\le \theta\le\pi/2$.

Comment: That's i know but in some cases other than circle i have to do more complex substitutions then how will i determine?

Comment: In exactly the same way. Work out the integration region with a sketch and calculate the required values of the substituted variables to cover the entire region.

Comment: Is there any other way other then sketch? Like in single integration  we just put values of limits and find corresponding variable limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region is just the part of $\{(x,y): x^{2}+y^{2} \leq a^{2}\}$ in the first quadrant. Hence the limts are $0<r<a$ and $0<\theta<\frac {\pi} 2$